# React-pro-sidebar how to set main content

Tags: react-sidebar

When i try to set component as main content when using react-pro-sidebar i can't place the component correctly in the main content position
here my result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZWOv.png)
here my SideBar and Layout:

```
function SideBar() {
  const { collapseSidebar } = useProSidebar();

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '500px'}}>
      <Sidebar width='200px'>
        <Menu>
          <MenuItem
              className="menu1"
              icon={
                <MenuRoundedIcon/>
              }
              onClick={() => {
                collapseSidebar();
              }}
            >
              <h3>Dashboard</h3>
            </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem component={<Link to="/posts" />} icon={<ArticleIcon/>}> Posts</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem icon={<ExitToAppIcon/>}> Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </Sidebar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
function Layout() {
  return ( 
    <>
      <NavBar/> 
      <SideBar/>
      <Outlet />
    </>
    );
}

export default Layout;
```

here my App:

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <AuthContextProvider>
            <ProSidebarProvider>
                <Routes>
                  <Route path="/" element={<Login />}/>
                  <Route element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />}/>
                  </Route>
                </Routes>
            </ProSidebarProvider>
          </AuthContextProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

i tried follow doc but its hard to render element with route in sidebar like that

```
import { Sidebar, Menu, MenuItem } from 'react-pro-sidebar';

      () => (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '100%', minHeight: '400px' }}>
          <Sidebar>
            <Menu>
              <MenuItem> Documentation</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem> Calendar</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem> E-commerce</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem> Examples</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
          </Sidebar>
//here
          <main style={{ padding: 10 }}> Main content</main>
        </div>
    );
      )
```